# Program crashes with empty text field

Tags: java, android, text, if-statement, textfield

I need help trying to fix my code.  I thought it was simple (probably is) but I can't get it.  I am have a simple adding calculator.  It works fine, but if I leave 1 or both Number text fields empty, the program crashes.

I have my if statement, but apparently I am not telling it to do the right thing.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Double firstNum, secondNum, answerNum;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText first = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtFirst);
    final EditText second = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSecond);


    final TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAnswer);



    Button calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalc);
    calc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // convert pulled info to double using variable names
            firstNum = Double.parseDouble(first.getText().toString());
            secondNum = Double.parseDouble(second.getText().toString());

            if (first == null || second == null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {

            // add numbers
            answerNum = (firstNum + secondNum);
            //set format
            DecimalFormat total = new DecimalFormat ("###,###,###.##");
            answer.setText("Answer is " + total.format(answerNum));
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to validate edittext means try this following code it will work fine.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
double firstNum = 0;
double secondNum = 0, answerNum;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText first = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final EditText second = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    final TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    Button calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    calc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            if (first.getText().toString().equals("")
                    || second.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter value",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                firstNum = Double.parseDouble(first.getText().toString());
                secondNum = Double.parseDouble(second.getText().toString());
                answerNum = (firstNum + secondNum);
                DecimalFormat total = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###.##");
                answer.setText("Answer is " + total.format(answerNum));
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have exception because of line: `Double.parseDouble(second.getText().toString())`, it cannot parse empty string to double, so you should add some validation code.